# compare strings in text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file that i need to compare the first 8 characters of everyline,and join these lines as one line where there is a match.The logic i have used is to pick each line starting with the first and compare it to the rest of the lines,then move to the second line and do the same upto the last line.but when i try to loop through the other lines for comparison i get error "index and length must refer to location within the string".

Please advise,see below code.

```
while ((line1 = fileread.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    counter2++;

    while ((line2 =fileread.ReadLine()) != null) 
    {                        
        if (line1.Substring(0, 8) == line2.Substring(0, 8))
        {
            line1 = line1 + " " + line2;
        }
        counter3++;
    }                    

    filewrite.WriteLine(line1);
    counter1++;
}
```

Comment: Hint: What happens when a line has less than 8 characters?

Comment: check the Length property of your strings...

Comment: Hint2: use a buffer. don't write to file in the same loop you read from it, otherwise you may encounter some unexpected results.

Comment: Why Dont you check condition like this
`while ((line2 =fileread.ReadLine()).Lenght>=8)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the length of ste string before you use `Substring`, use the `Length` property.

```
while ((line2 =fileread.ReadLine()) != null) 
{          
    if (line1.Length >=8 && lines2.Length >=8 &&
        line1.Substring(0, 8) == line2.Substring(0, 8))
    {
        line1 = line1 + " " + line2;
    }
    counter3++;
}
```